# Is it ethical to upload phonebook data to our own server via android app?

Tags: android

My android app is running great; now in order to increase virality I am planning to read phonebook contacts of a user and upload them to my server!
Then further I plan to process contacts and give relevant invite suggestion to my existing users on my application!
Is this ethical? Are there any official documentation regarding the same?

Comment: User will not trust on your app if you will save their contacts on your server.

Comment: I would delete and mark the app as spam if some one tries to "Now in order to increase virality I am planning to read phonebook contacts of a user and upload them to my server!"/.

Comment: You can make privacy policy and aware users, take permission from users and if they grant permission, you can do that...

Comment: This question does not belong here.

Comment: @chintak Patel -- thank you for a serious comment! 
Thats what my main point was, if user is granting permission and we have this in privacy policy then it will not be reported spam by internal checking by playstore right ?
Is there any official documentation regarding the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know (not a Lawyer!) in Germany (possibly all of Europe), that would even be illegal!
To save some ones private data, like a Phone-Number, you need THAT PERSONS permission! So, even if you think saving the data of people who never gave you permission to do so is ethical, the law say: No, don't do it!

PS:
Taking from this [page](https://www.wirtschaftswissen.de/unternehmensgruendung-und-fuehrung/datenschutz/kundendatenschutz/bundesdatenschutzgesetz-wann-sie-personenbezogene-daten-erheben-speichern-und-nutzen-duerfen/) regarding the situation in Germany:
 - All Storage of private Data is forbidden unless explicitly permitted.
 - If you safe Data, you must have a valid reason, and may not use the data for anything else
 - You have to answer requests from people whose Data you have about what data you have and how you use it.
  - It is your duty to only collect and store private Data when it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ethical or not, think about other possible outcomes of Your decision.

There are privacy sensitive users that will not use app if it wants too much information or they can't understand how and why is their data used.

In some countries there are laws describing what information can be requested, processed and for what purposes. By ignoring those You can get yourself in serious troubles.